# PHP Associative array from encoded data

Tags: php, arrays

I'm kinda new to php and mysql so this could be something as simple as a syntax error or something but I'm having no luck with using other examples.

The array in my db (JSON encoded):

```
["[\"option1\"=\u003E\"1\",\"someotherthing\"=\u003E\"abc\"]",""]
```

Fetching JSON encoded array from UserData:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT UserData FROM users WHERE Username=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $Username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $json = json_decode($data['UserData']);
    echo $json[0];
}
```

Result:

```
["option1"=>"1","someotherthing"=>"abc"]
```

Why is it that replacing "echo $json[0];" with "echo $json['option1'];" won't work, although the array is decoded?

EDIT: got it sorted! Does the trick by using the following:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT UserData FROM users WHERE Username=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $Username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $json = json_decode($data['UserData']);
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($json),true);
    echo $array['test'];
}
```

Comment: Try `print_r($data[0])`

Comment: @ASR I've done that and I get this:
Array
(
    [0] => ["option1"=>"1","someotherthing"=>"abc"]
)

how can I use the values and keys?

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_fetch_all()` if you are only expecting only 1 row returned. use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` -> `$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`, as then you can do `$data['option1']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't the best way to go about storing data. As you see, it's being stored in your database as a [`PHP code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). If you're looking to access the variables in this array then you're going to have a hard time!

A more *"common"* way of achieving what you're after is storing `JSON` in the database and accessing it.

```
//....other code....
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
$json = json_decode($data);

echo $json->someotherthing;
```

---

As [*@Sean noted in his comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581316/php-array-being-returned-incorrectly/37581380#comment62649487_37581316), you're fetching a collection of data instead of one row. You can do that by harnessing [`$MYSQLI->fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to return an associative array.

---

#### Edit

This is an edit to your question. You're still storing a string array as json. That's why you can't access it. I assume you have an actual array. This is the way you'd want to store said data:

```
// example array
$array = array('test' => 'hello', 'derp' => 'herp');
// encode it
$json = json_encode($array);
// store it
// DO YOUR MYSQLI INSERT, ETC...
```

Comment: Hi @Darren, thanks for the tips. I have revised my code and made it similar to yours, however using "echo $json->someotherthing" gives me the following error: "Trying to get property of non-object...". Please see my updated question.

Comment: @LankyMoose I've edited my answer! See the bottom. It's in relation to how you're storing your actual data.

Comment: What is the difference between storing "a string" and "JSON"?

Comment: @yourcommonsense he's trying to put an array in. This is a more manageable way of dealing with the data then trying to convert a "string array" to something useful